# Zapier issue - can't find a Webhook sample

Tags: arduino, zapier

can anyone help me? I'm working on an [Arduino Project called Plant Communicator](https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/arduino/plant-communicator-7ea06f)

My problem is when setting up a Zap to send emails containing temperature, moisture, light, etc I can't get past the Find data stage. Zapier pauses/skips the test stating that Zapier had trouble  finding a sample. Without this stage complete, I can't continue with this project.

Can anyone offer any advice?

Thanks

Joe

Comment: Don't you have any code?

Comment: Hi Ruud. Not sure what code you are referring to? I'm not working in Arduino IDE yet, I am stuck on the first stage of setting up a Zap on Zapier that automatically sends plant data via email. I can't get past the Zap stage setting up a Webhook. https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/arduino/plant-communicator-7ea06f